# Why can't I do cast?

Tags: java, android, ratingbar

I need to change the colors of the stars `ratingBar` but get an exception, why it occurs and that is perfectly accepted?

ResultActivity

```
private void setDados() {
        TextView text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView3);
        text.setText((text.getText()) + "" + corretas);
        RatingBar ratingBar = (RatingBar) findViewById(R.id.ratingBar);
        ratingBar.setRating((100*corretas)/(corretas+erradas));
        LayerDrawable stars = (LayerDrawable) ratingBar.getProgressDrawable();
        try {
            stars.getDrawable(2).setColorFilter(Color.YELLOW, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Log

```
04-18 22:02:39.828  31732-31732/com.morais.daniela.doctorquiz E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.morais.daniela.doctorquiz/com.morais.daniela.doctorquiz.Activity.ResultActivity}: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.support.v7.internal.widget.TintDrawableWrapper cannot be cast to android.graphics.drawable.LayerDrawable
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1967)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1992)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:127)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1158)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4448)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:823)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:590)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.support.v7.internal.widget.TintDrawableWrapper cannot be cast to android.graphics.drawable.LayerDrawable
            at com.morais.daniela.doctorquiz.Activity.ResultActivity.setDados(ResultActivity.java:44)
            at com.morais.daniela.doctorquiz.Activity.ResultActivity.onCreate(ResultActivity.java:36)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1931)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1992)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:127)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1158)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4448)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:823)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:590)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

****UPDATE****: This doesn't work in API 5.0 and higher, how I do for works in Ice Cream and higher? Without need to create a star image

Comment: Post all of your code for `ResultActivity`. Plus your error seems to be about:  `android.support.v7.internal.widget.TintDrawableWrapper cannot be cast to android.graphics.drawable.LayerDrawable`.

Comment: Similar question and answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17267921/950427.

Comment: The line 44 is `LayerDrawable stars = (LayerDrawable) ratingBar.getProgressDrawable();`. according to a comment in another question doesn't work on API 5.0 and up http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2446270/android-ratingbar-change-star-colors

Comment: This really sucks. A method for "higher versions" and another method for older versions is necessary?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because tinting drawables was introduced with Android 5 the appcompat-v7 library wraps drawables in `TintDrawable` class. You can get around it using reflection. Use [this gist](https://gist.github.com/consp1racy/d315b125a305546f2330) and then this snippet:

```
LayerDrawable stars = (LayerDrawable) XpeceDrawableWrapper.getDrawable(ratingBar.getProgressDrawable());
```

Be sure to call `ratingBar.setProgressDrawable(stars)` to replace the originally tinted drawable.

**EDIT:** The gist as it is is probably incompatible with proguard (a couple of keep class rules should mend it).

Answer (score 0):

[getPorgressDrawable](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ProgressBar.html#getProgressDrawable()) returns a [Drawable](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/Drawable.html) object. [LayerDrawable](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/LayerDrawable.html) extends Drawable.

You are explicitly casting a `Drawable` object to `LayerDrawable`, which concludes to runtime error, because a `Drawable` object **is not** a `LayerDrawable`. Only a `LayerDrawable` object is `Drawable`.

You might want to take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5289393/casting-variables-in-java) about Type Casting in Java.

Answer (score 0):

The cleanest way would be to define your own `Drawable` like suggested here: [Android RatingBar change star colors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2446270/android-ratingbar-change-star-colors)

The casting error is because of android support library. The support library wraps the most of android widgets drawables into a [TintDrawableWrapper](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/421d8baa4a524e1384bcf033360bccaf8d55081d/v7/appcompat/src/android/support/v7/internal/widget/TintDrawableWrapper.java) which extends [DrawableWrapper](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/421d8baa4a524e1384bcf033360bccaf8d55081d/v7/appcompat/src/android/support/v7/internal/widget/DrawableWrapper.java). You can access the real (wrapped) drawable only by using reflections to access field

```
private final Drawable mDrawable;
```

which should be the `LayerDrawable` you are looking for.

But be aware that the name of the field could be changed with any support library update at any time.

Another "hacky" way is to use the tinting methods

```
public void setTint(int tint);
public void setTintList(ColorStateList tint)
```

which are defined in `DrawableWrapper`. Since `DrawableWrapper` has package visiblity you have to write a little helper class and put it into `android.support.v7.internal.widget` package to access these methods

Answer (score 0):

Came accross a similar issue today when creating a RatingBar programmatically. The following workaround is working for me also on **Android 4.x** devices using the AppCompatRatingBar:

```
AppCompatRatingBar rb = new AppCompatRatingBar(activity);
LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
layoutParams.gravity = Gravity.CENTER;
rb.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
rb.setStepSize(1.0f);
rb.setMax(5);

LayerDrawable layerDrawable = null;
if (rb.getProgressDrawable() instanceof LayerDrawable) {
    layerDrawable = (LayerDrawable) rb.getProgressDrawable();
} else if (rb.getProgressDrawable() instanceof DrawableWrapper) {
    DrawableWrapper wrapper = (DrawableWrapper) rb.getProgressDrawable();
    if (wrapper.getWrappedDrawable() instanceof LayerDrawable) {
        layerDrawable = (LayerDrawable) wrapper.getWrappedDrawable();
    }
}

if (layerDrawable != null) {
    layerDrawable.getDrawable(2).setColorFilter(Color.WHITE, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);
    layerDrawable.getDrawable(0).setColorFilter(Color.WHITE, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);
    layerDrawable.getDrawable(1).setColorFilter(ContextCompat.getColor(activity, R.color.primary), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);
}
```